# child_process.spawn stdout coming in chunks

Tags: node.js, linux, stdout, child-process

I am trying to run a binary file on linux that outputs via stdout. If I run it from the terminal, I get a beautiful stream of data printing out (close to one line every 50 ms) but if I run it from a nodeJS script with child_process.spawn, the data arrives in chunks every 5 seconds or so.

Code snippet:

```
 const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;


    // Run all node binaries
for (let i = 0; i < config.dependencies.length; i++) {

  // Get details on this binary
  var repo = config.dependencies[i].name;
  var version = config.dependencies[i].version;
  console.log("Running: " + repo + ' version ' + version);


  // Run this binary
    node_process[i] = spawn('./'+repo+'/'+repo,[], {stdio: ['pipe', 'pipe', 'pipe']})

    node_process[i].stdout.on('data', function(data) {

    stdout_data=config.dependencies[i].name+ ":"+data.toString();
    console.log("Stdout: " + stdout_data)

});
}
```

I think I have everything setup to print the data from stdout realtime, and I'm very confused as to why this doesn't work as expected. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it figured out! Use this command when spawning:

```
spawn('stdbuf', ['-i0', '-o0', '-e0', FilePath])
```

Uses stdbuf to spawn it with no buffer.

Comment: Sadly did not fix it for me :(